# Worpdress function for difference dates

Tags: posts, date

can I show for each posts the insert date like as '1 hours ago', '2 days ago', '2 weeks ago', etc..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Put this in the appropriate template.

```
<?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?>
```

Normally the php file you should look for would be entry-meta.php

Remember to use a child theme..

Comment: @Eleonorarossini great it works ;-) can you please mark the answer as the correct one? Many thanks!